# Does Chekov believe his claims?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

So, in Star Trek: The Original Series, the character [Pavel Chekov](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Pavel_Chekov) was introduced in the second season.  Among his quirks is claiming that a [whole bunch](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Pavel_Chekov#Russian_heritage) of things were invented in Russia.  For a small sampling from that page:

> - He claimed that the old Earth saying: "Fool me once, shame on you. Fool me twice, shame on me," was invented in Russia. (TOS: "Friday's
>     Child")
> - He claimed that the English story about the Cheshire Cat was a Russian story about a disappearing cat from Minsk. (TOS: "Who Mourns
>     for Adonais?")
> - He claimed that the Garden of Eden was located just outside Moscow. He claimed that it was "a very nice place" and that "it must've made
>     Adam and Eve very sad to leave." Which Kirk sarcastically responded
>     with "Just..outside Moscow, all right" (TOS: "The Apple")

Is there any evidence that Chekov actually believes all his claims<sup>1</sup>, or was he intentionally messing with the rest of the crew?

<sup>1</sup>Minus the sarcastic "tsar of all the Russias" to Apollo.

Comment: In the real world, groups of people develop in-jokes and gags that are slightly odd to outsiders. I always took Chekov's "in-Soviet-Russia-we-made-all-the-things" attitude to be one of those wonderful running jokes that's being made by both the writers and the character.

Comment: Adam and Eve were 100% Russian. How do you know? They had no cloths to wear, only an apple to eat, no sex, and called their life circumstances "Paradise". BTW, this is 100% authentic Soviet joke :)

Comment: That's the same category as Klingon Shakespeare :)

Comment: BTW, "tsar of all the Russias" is a nearly correct literal translation of the official title of the monarch ("Государь Всея Руси")

Comment: Al Gore invented the internet!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This joke was a throwback to a typical "This was invented in Russia" (aka "Russia is the Birthplace of Elephants", or "[Россия — родина слонов](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_%E2%80%94_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2)"), which referred to Soviet attempts to brainwash people into the fact that the Motherland invented everything (in some interesting ways, sometimes correct - such as the case with radios: Popov's radio came before Marconi's, but he didn't bother patenting it AFAIR).

(Of course, in a special ***meta*** bit of irony, the phrase "Russia is the birthplace of elephants" itself was apparently first uttered not by a Russian, but by a spanish traveler in 18th century, who saw mammoth remains in St. Petersburg museum).

**Most of the people using the phrase for the last 70-80 years in USSR/Russia used it ironically/sarcastically** unless they were Party Leaders, therefore, Chekov coudn't possibly be serious.

Comment: Not to be confused with a different "Russia is the place of the biggest X", culminating in "Russia is the place of the biggest microchips!"

Comment: Interesting...  there doesn't really seem to be anything about this phenomenon in English (discounting [translating that page](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FРоссия_—_родина_слонов), at least), so, it's basically a Russian version of "[Everything's bigger in Texas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas-sized)"?

Comment: @Izkata - quite correct, the "biggest X" is 100% the same. Same psychological thing, stemming from the same geographical underpinnings

Comment: “therefore, Chekov coudn't possibly be serious” — unless [World War III](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/World_War_III) meant that Chekov had heard the claims, but wasn’t aware that they were generally used as jokes.

Comment: Note that Chekov is noted explicitly as making other (non-Russia related jokes like "So close we can smell them" in *Tribble*